# How to add a separate CSS file for .scss files using webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I have a pretty simple JavaScript app I'm compiling using Webpack. I have the application splitting into two separate bundles now - `App` and `Vendor`. `App` contains my custom code while the  `vendor` files contains the frameworks.

The `app` bundle contains all the JavaScript in my `app` directory, but there are also some Sass files in there as well. I'm trying to get those to compile into a separate CSS bundle file.

Through some research, I figured out I needed to use the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` with a webpack Sass compiler and style loaders.

Here is my `webpack.config` file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: {
        app: './app.module.js',
        vendor: ['angular','angular-route']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/bundle',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-    loader", "css-loader") }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */'vendor', /* filename= */'vendor.bundle.js'),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

I have the following dependencies installed using npm:

```
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"node-sass": "^3.8.0",
"sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^1.13.1"
```

The problem is when I bundle using webpack, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../node_modules/css-loader/index.js
```

And

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../node_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js
```

I'm only including one sass file in my main application file at the moment. In my main `app.js` file, I have: `require('./styles.scss')` Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

To those of you that may be having the same issue, and you're running Windows, the following solution worked for me:

At the top of our `webpack.config` add the following:

```
var path = require('path');
```

Then change where you define your context to:

```
context: path.resolve(__dirname, "folder_name")
```